# How can I display another view in a seperate storyboard

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, swift, storyboard

So what I am trying to do is have a separate story board for all of the buttons in my app. EX for each of the buttons below I want it to take it to another storyboard with more then one view controller where I can then do separate screen switching for each number in the range specified below and at the end have a quick quiz. But if I use a single storyboard all the screens would be to clustered to work with. Because in my main menu I have three lesson options (Numbers, General communication, Travel) each of those have 10 sub-lessons and each sub-lesson has 10 signs then a quiz at the end.

[image]

So in my xcode project I have the storyboards:

- Main
- 0-9
- 10-19
- etc...

How can I switch from the Main storyboard to 0-9's storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you create one generic view and show what you want there? You can send the data(which quiz you have selected) through prepareForSeque function and then in the view controller prepare data you want to show. I think that every quiz have something in common, or you can group them as a true/false, MCMA and MCSA. Just a suggestion.

Just read your comment, can you relate to statements above?

To answer your question:

```
UIStoryboard *story = [UIStoryboard
                                         storyboardWithName:@"storyboard_name"
                                         bundle:nil];

CustomViewController *controller= [story  instantiateInitialViewController];
```

After this you can push controller to navigation stack or something like this:

```
[self.navigationController pushViewController:controller animated:YES];
```

Ofcourse, if you want to do this via IB you can extend UIStoryboardSegue and do similar logic there.

Since I am a bit blind, I pasted objetive c code, not swift code.
Here you go:

```
let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "myStoryboardName", bundle: nil)
let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("myVCID") as UIViewController
self.presentViewController(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: The reason why is because if I were to do it that way I would have about 300 windows for the 3 lessons I have from the main menu (numbers, basic signs, travel) which each have 10 sub lessons of 10 signs per sub lesson

Comment: Edited, please check.

Comment: You should organize your data separately. If you ever find yourself making the same thing over and over again, you should make a class for it and just pass different data to it (ie. 1 lesson class and 1 sublessor class)

Comment: Thank you sadly this is throwing exceptions in swift

Comment: CustomViewController is owner of the scene in storyboard, have you set that ?

Comment: No... Embarrassingly enough I actually don't know how to do that. I am horribly sorry this is my first non game non objective C app.

Comment: well, the same as in objective c - Identity inspector. When you set that, you call that class in code snipet above

Comment: That is set! and was set but is still throwing 9 errors after making some formatting errors but with your raw code it was throwing 12 errors

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67705/discussion-between-ondeckshooting-and-nickcatib).

Comment: Hey, mark answer as correct if you have found it helpfull :)